# Proof By Contradiction where p always proves q true

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, boolean

Prove that for any even integer n, n^2 mod 2 = 0 using proof by contradiction. (Question)

- Let p: any even integer n
- Let q: n^2 mod 2 = 0

In this example, if proved by contradiction, I'll be assuming ~(p → q) = p ∧ ~q = true.

With this, ~q can never be proven at all so long as p remains.
How do I solve this question via **proof by contradiction** then?

Would doing ~p and ~q be the same? This would seem like inverse (~p → ~q) or contrapositive (~q → ~p) instead.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Why are you concerned about proving $\neg q$? Your job is to assume $p \wedge \neg q$ and use this to derive a contradiction.  

In this case, you must show that if $n$ is even but $n^2 \neq 0 \pmod 2$, then something impossible would be the case. (I.e., some statement would be both true a false; a contradiction.)